# Why a System.Windows.Forms.Timer inside UserControl does not fire its Tick event?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a UserControl on which I added a System.Windows.Forms.Timer. The Timer was added at Design Time. The Enabled property is False by default. I just changed its Interval to 400ms.

The UserControl gets added to the form programmatically. The timer is Disabled at design time. At runtime the timer gets enabled by a Property Setter of the UserControl.

The UserControl class is this:

```
Public Class LuminaireSign
   Public Property MyLuminaire As Luminaire
Private _state As LuminaireSignState
Public Property State As LuminaireSignState
    Get
        Return _state
    End Get
    Set(value As LuminaireSignState)
        If value <> _state Then
            _state = value

            If _state = LuminaireSignState.OK Then
                Timer1.Enabled = False
                Me.Image = luminSign_Green
            Else
                Timer1.Enabled = True
            End If

        End If
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByRef associatedLumin As Luminaire)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    MyLuminaire = associatedLumin
    AddHandler MyLuminaire.PropertyChanged, New PropertyChangedEventHandler(AddressOf propChanged)
End Sub

Private Sub propChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    If e.PropertyName = "Status" Then
        If MyLuminaire.Status.BatteryEmpty Then
            State = LuminaireSignState.Fault
        Else
            State = LuminaireSignState.OK
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The strange thing is that even though the timer gets Enabled, timer's Tick event does not get fired.

As you can see I set the State property by the Sub propChanged() which is a PropertyChangedEventHandler that handles MyLuminaire.PropertyChanged. MyLuminaire is passed by reference in the UserControl's constructor. The actual Luminaire object's Status is set in a non-UI thread.

Could it not tick because the propChanged event gets fired via a non-UI thread property change?
Can someone explain me what is going on?

PS. If I Enable the timer at design time, the Tick event fires well until the timer gets Disabled once. Then again even if the timer gets Enabled it does not fire the Tick event.

Comment: How is your timer Initialized ? how is it declared ? do you want your timer to start ticking when setting the property LuminaireSignState ?

Comment: I just tested and, as expected, the `Tick` event of a `Timer` in that scenario is raised. Either something is corrupt on your system or there is something else at play.  Most likely the `Enabled` property is not being set when you think it is due to faulty logic.  Have you debugged your code properly, i.e. have you placed breakpoints on the lines that set the `Enabled` property to make sure that they are executed when you expect? I'll wager that they're not.

Comment: @sapi I updated the question. Yes i want the timer to start ticking when setting the property LuminaireSignState.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have debugged very well and triple checked that the timer gets enabled. What do you mean by "something is corrupt on your system"?

Comment: If you set the `Enabled` property of a `Timer`, it raises its `Tick` event.  That's what a `Timer` does. That's how it works for everyone the world over. If that's not happening for you then something must be broken on your system, e.g. something in your project or something in your IDE. That's all there is to it. You should provide us with a minimal example that demonstrates the issue that we can replicate ourselves. If you can't replicate the issue in a test project then there's an issue with your project. If you can but we can't then it's your system.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I updated the question.. I created a test project with propertychanged and it worked. The only thing different is that in test project I cause the MyLuminaire.status setting using a button. In the real project MyLuminaire.status is set by a non-UI thread.

Comment: "In the real project MyLuminaire.status is set by a non-UI thread".  That could well be the issue. While it's not a control, the WinForms `Timer` is specifically intended for single-threaded environments. You probably need to marshal a call to the UI thread to enable and disable it. Given that you're enabling and disabling the `Timer` in a property of a control though, you should already be on the UI thread. You should be marshaling a call to the UI thread to set that property in the first place. that's the rule for using controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the propertyChanged is happening in a background thread and thus the timer could not fire the Tick event. So we have to enable the timer in a thread-safe way!

The solution is to not set timer1.Enabled directly but instead create a sub (see SetStateOk) that sets the timer1 and a delegate for this sub to be called whenever InvokeRequired = true.

So change the State Property and add a call the SetStateOk Sub and problem solved:

```
Public Property State As LuminaireSignState
Get
    Return _state
End Get
Set(value As LuminaireSignState)
    If value <> _state Then
        _state = value

        If _state = LuminaireSignState.OK Then
             SetStateOk(true)
            'Timer1.Enabled = False
            'Me.Image = luminSign_Green
        Else
            SetStateOk(false)
            'Timer1.Enabled = True
        End If

    End If
End Set
End Property


Private Delegate Sub SetStateOKDelegate(ByVal stateIsOk As Boolean)

Private Sub SetStateOK(ByVal stateIsOk As Boolean)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New SetStateOKDelegate(AddressOf SetStateOK), New Object() {stateIsOk})
    Else
        If stateIsOk Then
            timer1.Enabled = False
            Image = luminSign_Green
        Else
            timer1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This way the timer gets enabled and Tick event get's fired regularly!